# Changing node box size in Partykit

Tags: party

I'd like to be able to change the size of the box to fit the text using the `partykit` package.  How do I do that? [Node Box Size Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQtwZ.jpg)

Comment: The best way to deal with this that I've found so far is simply to use `rpart.plot`.  (Assuming you've created the tree in `rpart`.)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided a reproducible example and hence I'm not 100% sure - but I think the plot you have created used the `node_terminal()` panel-generating function to draw the terminal nodes, see `?node_terminal` for more details.

By default, the function automatically determines the height/width of the boxes depending on the character labels that are going to be drawn. It uses `length(label) + 1` lines as the `height` and the maximum of `nchar(label)` as the width. However, you can easily change the height/width by `plot(..., tp_args = list(height = ..., width = ...))` to values that you find more suitable.